# retrieve weekly values over a period of two years

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to show a last 15 weeks trend graph for which I am querying a table that stores the values in daily basis. I am using the below query:

```
select avg(kpi_values),to_char(kpi_date, 'IW') 
  from (select * from kpi_thresholds)
 where KPI_NAME='SEARCH_KPI' 
   and to_number(to_char(kpi_date, 'IW')) 
       between 
       to_number(to_char(to_date('12-JAN-15 16:30:13','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'IW'))-15 
       and 
       to_number(to_char(to_date('12-JAN-15 16:30:13','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'IW')) 
 group 
    by to_char(kpi_date, 'IW') order by to_char(kpi_date, 'IW') asc;
```

The query return proper result but only for the weeks that fall in year 2015 (ie. only 2 weeks), but I need to show last 15 weeks value for which i need to consider 2014 weeks too.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `from (select * from kpi_thresholds)` is useless, you could just do `from kpi_thresholds`

Comment: Is `'12-JAN-14 16:30:13'` for both dates a typo? You don't include 2015 at all. Do you need the results to always start at the beginning of the weeks or do just want to go back 7*15 days?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - i need to go back 7 * 15 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need the dates aligned with "week boundaries" this becomes quite simple:

```
where kpi_date between 
          timestamp '2015-01-12 16:30:00' - interval '7' day * 15
      and timestamp '2015-01-12 16:30:00'
```

Note that this would not return rows with a kpi_date from 2014-09-29 *before* 16:30

This can be written a bit shorter in Oracle

```
where kpi_date between 
          timestamp '2015-01-12 16:30:00' - 7 * 15
      and timestamp '2015-01-12 16:30:00'
```

Comment: Just a small note: If `kpi_date` is a `DATE` datatype, using ANSI `timestamp` literals like this will *implicitly* turn this into `where cast(kpi_date as timestamp) between timestamp ...` , which may give you an unwanted full table scan. It may be more typing to use `to_date(...)`, but it can use an index if there is one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `to_char(kpi_date, 'IW')` the last 15 weeks will have values 40, 41, ..., 53, 1, 2. And your where clause asks for those with week value between -13 and 2.

Instead group and order by `trunc(kpi_date, 'IW')` which will include the year. In the select you can do `to_char` on the truncated date value to get what you need. In the SQL below I use `'IYYY-IW'` to show you the results, if you only need the week number, you can just use `'IW'` in the `to_char`.

And then in your `where` clause do not use a function on the column that you are using for predicate (that would typically preclude the optimizer from using an index), instead calculate the beginning and end date values for >= and <.

As I haven't got some test-data, this is untried code:

```
select avg(kpi_values)
     , to_char(trunc(kpi_date, 'IW'), 'IYYY-IW') 
  from kpi_thresholds
 where KPI_NAME='SEARCH_KPI' 
   and kpi_date >= trunc(to_date('12-JAN-15 16:30:13','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'IW') - 15*7
   and kpi_date <  trunc(to_date('12-JAN-15 16:30:13','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'IW') + 7
 group by trunc(kpi_date, 'IW')
 order by trunc(kpi_date, 'IW') asc;
```